# Limit $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( \frac{\sqrt[2]{2}+\sqrt[4]{4}+...+\sqrt[2n]{2n}}{1+\sqrt[3]{3}+...\sqrt[2n-1]{2n-1}} \right) ^n$

Tags: limits

How to find this limit $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( \frac{\sqrt[2]{2}+\sqrt[4]{4}+...+\sqrt[2n]{2n}}{1+\sqrt[3]{3}+...\sqrt[2n-1]{2n-1}} \right) ^n$? Maybe is there a simple way?

Comment: ...why though...?

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$ k^{1/k} = \exp\left(\frac{\log k}{k}\right) = 1+\frac{\log k}{k}+O\left(\frac{\log^2 k}{k^2}\right)\tag{1} $$
the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt[2k-1]{2k-1}$ does not deviate from $n$ by much more that $\log^2 n$.
 It follows that the given limit equals
$$ \exp\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\sqrt[2n]{2n}-\sqrt[2n-1]{2n-1}\right)\tag{2}$$
where the involved series is converging, always due to $(1)$.
Numerically the limit is $\approx 1.206664139$.